# Can you use a crossbow with Arrow Storm?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, weapons, ranged-attack

Can a crossbow be used for Arrow Storm, or do you *have* to have a short/longbow?

Answer (score 4):

The 3rd-level ranger spell *arrow storm* [trans] (*Spell Compendium* 16) says only that the caster, after casting the spell, "can use a full-round action
to make one ranged attack with a bow with which you are proficient against every foe within a distance equal to the weapon’s range increment." Without a house rule, this likely limits the caster to making attacks with a longbow, shortbow, and composite and similar exotic versions of them and prohibits employing the spell *arrow storm* in conjunction with hand, light, heavy, repeating, and other exotic crossbows.

However, this *is* anecdotal—[the game never says explicitly crossbows *aren't* bows](https://xkcd.com/1552/). But, for example, the *Player's Handbook* says, ["When using a bow, a character can draw ammunition as a free action; crossbows and slings require an action for reloading"](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/weapons.html#projectile-weapons) (113). Further, for example, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* says, ["Bows, crossbows, and slings so crafted bestow the *chaotic* power upon their ammunition"](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsAW.html#anarchic) (223), when it instead could've said—were *bows* to typically to include crossbows—, *Bows and slings so crafted*…. Finally, I could (after an admittedly cursory search) find *no* instances of *bow* actually *including* crossbows. So make of that what you will.

But, really, just because the rules are against it doesn't mean no attempt should be made to convince the DM that a crossbow-using ranger somewhere might've come up with a similar and widely available *bolt storm* spell. I can't imagine such a spell would somehow *destroy game balance* (at least anymore than the regular *arrow storm* spell does—that is, *not much*), especially since crossbows are widely viewed as inferior to bows anyway.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the reload issue?

Comment: @Miniman I don't *think* so? I mean, the spell *arrow storm* doesn't care if there're a billion folks within the bow's first increment, and, while the DM *could* limit the character to a certain number of free actions (like drawing an arrow is), the spell's specificity *should* override even the DM's limit. Conveniently carrying the billion arrows (or bolts) required to *make* all those ranged attacks with the weapon would be the *real* problem.

Comment: The general assumption is you would have hand crossbow focus or rapid reload. Or the quick loading enchant.

Comment: @Masakan The spell says "bow", not "crossbow". Faster reloading doesn't matter.